# Create standalone executable with CMake

Tags: c++, dll, cmake

I need to build a standalone executable. The main problem is that this project relies on dll which I previously built on my system.

When I create the executable there should not be a dependence from these dll so I need to know if I can include them somehow in the program. To compile I'm currently using CMake which I believe is the best solution, but I haven't figured a way to accomplish this task yet.

Right now in my `CMakeLists.txt` file I do the following:

```
find_package(ITK REQUIRED)

include(${ITK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(myexe myexe.cxx)

target_link_libraries(myexe
${ITK_LIBRARIES} )
```

I omitted some instructions to focus on what's most important. When I compile it, it correctly works but it is not standalone as it still keeps using the dll (also tried with .a) installed on my system.

Thanks

Comment: What `dll` do you mean, `ITK`? Is your question that how can you build `myexe` executable so that it does not need `ITK` libraries at runtime?

Comment: Are you working on Linux or Windows? You mentioned both `dll` (usually Windows shared library) and `.a` (usually Linux static library)

Comment: sorry for my bed explaination. I am working on Windows and i've just compiled static libraries for itk (and vtk). The file generated have a .a extension which as far as i know is suitable for Windows too. So i need to build this executable so that it won't need itk at runtime

Answer (score 1):

A DLL is by nature dynamically linked to at runtime. Your only option is to use a static library (.lib on windows .

Comment: i'm compiling static libraries right now, thanks for the answer, once i'm done, do i need to add anything else to my CMakeLists.txt?